# Skype Web Control - Cant Log in

Tags: javascript, html, web, skype

I'm developing a website with a skype chat with the Skype Web Control code from the skype developer site.

It's basically 2 lines of code, it shouldn't really be that hard to do, but I'm receiving an error on the browser console when I'm trying to log in.

I press the login button and the pop up window to login appears, I fill the form and the popup closes. Now the chat doesn't change a bit, but if I close and open the chat it will display the conversation, so I actually logged in but it's not refreshing the chat automatically.

This is what i receive on the console:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
>   provided ('https://latest-swc.cdn.skype.com') does not match the
>   recipient window's origin ('https://swc.cdn.skype.com').

My current code:

```
<div class="skype-button bubble" data-contact-id="echo123" data-color="#2d4e87"></div>
<script src="https://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you put some code in your question?

Comment: I think you got this error because of URL mismatch that is in your skype app account and host URL of your running app.

Comment: @KiranShahi What is the skype app? Because I didn't set any URL for anything, it was pretty much copy paste.

Comment: @AnikHasibul I've added the code!

Comment: any solution for the same ?